# Unity Xcode project won't build/archive

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm in the process of releasing a Unity game to the App Store. I've used Unity to build the Xcode which seemed to work. But when I open the project in Xcode and choose "Product > Archive", it ends up failing. (I'm told that I have to do this in order to get the game on App Store Connect to release it.)

[Xcode Buildtime error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvi6x.png)

I'm using Unity 2020.3.48f1, on macOS 11.2.1, with Xcode 12.4. The Mac I'm using is an old Mac Mini and I can't update it to the newest version, therefore I can't update Xcode either.

Is there a solution to this problem on my current Mac? Or should I try to get my hands on a new one with the new version of macOS and Xcode?

Let me know if I should provide further information.